# Stopping users from going back to a previously submitted form

Tags: xampp

How do I stop users from going back to a previously asked question(Quiz page in php) on pressing the Back Button. All the questions are displayed one after the other and the entire code for this is in the same php file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track what the user has answered by using a cookie, session or database.